# ListView displays incorrect image for item

Tags: android

I can add images to my `ListView` and they can display, but if the items in the list are more than 8, the `ListView` displays a wrong image for the item. Here is my `newView()` method:

```java
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent){
    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View view = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
try{
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        String image = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RecipeClasses.Recipe.RECIPE_IMAGE));
        String recipe_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RecipeClasses.Recipe.RECIPE_NAME));

        Uri path = Uri.parse(image);
        TextView recipe_txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_recipe_row);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_view_recipe);
        if (new File(image).exists()) {
            ImageResizer img_W = new ImageResizer(context, img.getMeasuredWidth(), img.getMeasuredHeight());
            img_W.loadImage(image, img);
        } else {
            ImageResizer img_W = new ImageResizer(context, img.getMeasuredWidth(), img.getMeasuredHeight());
            img_W.loadImage(path, img);
            img.setImageURI(path);
        }

        if (recipe_txt != null){
            recipe_txt.setText(recipe_name);
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

    return view;
}
```

Comment: try this answer :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18049785/listview-showing-wrong-view-for-a-few-seconds-while-flinging-and-scrolling

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that your newView is similar to the getView method. Are you sure that the image you wanting to get for the 9th item is avaliable?

Try processing the Cursor into an ArrayList then it will be easier to manage in-order to determine the exact problem.

Also check the path format of the newly added images for the items as they could be incorrect when trying to assign them to that specified path.

Answer (score 0):

The way it is set up at the moment means it is inflating a new view every time you run through the adapter. This is expensive, especially with images.

Reuse the inital view with this check:

```
View v;
if (view == null) {
    view = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
}
```

This way the layout will only be inflated once and reused.