# Listview showing wrong view for a few seconds while flinging and scrolling

Tags: android, listview

The system seems to be recycling views until it loads the correct position's view in my listview, resulting in duplicated images and text for a few seconds.  Can anyone help?

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    Log.d("position",""+position);

    if(v==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_appinfo, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.ivAppIcon = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ivIconApp);
        holder.tvAppName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvNameApp);
        holder.progress = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.progress_spinner);
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }
    holder.ivAppIcon.setImageDrawable(null);
    holder.tvAppName.setText(null);
    holder.progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.ivAppIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    // Using an AsyncTask to load the slow images in a background thread
    new AsyncTask<ViewHolder, Void, Drawable>() {
        private ViewHolder v;
        private ResolveInfo entry = (ResolveInfo) mListAppInfo.get(position);

        @Override
        protected Drawable doInBackground(ViewHolder... params) {
            v = params[0];
            return entry.loadIcon(mPackManager);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // If this item hasn't been recycled already, hide the
            // progress and set and show the image
            v.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            v.ivAppIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            v.ivAppIcon.setImageDrawable(result);
            v.tvAppName.setText(entry.loadLabel(mPackManager));
        }
    }.execute(holder);
    return v;
}

static class ViewHolder {
      TextView tvAppName;
      ImageView ivAppIcon;
      ProgressBar progress;
      //int position;
}
```

It is almost as if the position is being set wrong for a few seconds.

Comment: getView is not the right position to put the asyncTask, let that run independently and when you have data available update your views calling notifydatasetchanged on adapter, in getView only check if image available otherwise show a default image. you can hold onto small version of images by using DiskLruCache, a class by google not part of framework but works fast. here just download images everytime a view comes in

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can let the ViewHolder hold a reference to the AsyncTask. When `convertView != null`, you can call `cancel()` on the AsyncTask held by the ViewHolder since you know the image it is loading will not be correct for this new row. In `doInBackgrond()` and `onPostExecute()`, first check `if(!isCancelled())` before doing anything.

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tvAppName;
    ImageView ivAppIcon;
    ProgressBar progress;
    AsyncTask task;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        /* inflate new view, make new ViewHolder, etc. */
        ...
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.task.cancel();
    }

    // always make a new AsyncTask, they cannot be reused
    holder.task = new AsyncTask ...
    holder.execute(...);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it shuts down the activity and acts like I was trying to execute the same AsyncTask twice at the same time, even though I called cancel(true); on it when the convertview != null.

Comment: Make sure you always create a new AsyncTask and set it in the ViewHolder.

Comment: Technically, onPostExecute() will never be called after cancel() has been called.  It is recommended to "check the value returned by isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]) to finish the task as early as possible."

Comment: Ya Im still seeing that flickering of the recycled image after wiring up you recommended cancelling mechanism of AsyncTasks https://plus.google.com/114796031671938974703/posts/gE4ECQ7qHYM

Comment: how you can do it with recycle views ? :S is other concept

Answer (score 2):

Android's developer documentation has a great section on this:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html

This issue, as stated above, is that your AsyncTask is keeping a hard reference to a view that's already been recycled.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the current items image view to a standard loading image or nothing right away when you provide the view via the adapter. This will always "reset" the image, while it is loaded on your async task. This is probably the best approach to keep the performance benefits of the recycled views. Same goes for the text.